ROS2 Iron ARM64 packages vanished
Since a few days several ARM64 images are gone from the package index e.g. ros-iron-ros2-control. Running apt-cache search ros-iron-ros2-control on an ARM machine yields no results. Does somebody know what happened there? The amd64 packages are still available though. My post on ROS Discourse is sadly pending for almost a week, so there is probably no help coming from this side.

For reference https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-iron-arm64-packages-vanished/38652/2
However, the last build was successful, hopefully this solves itself with the next iron sync.
you can try the testing repo in the meantime.

Sync happend last night!
